# How to compile project on Raspberry Pi, even when g++'s virtual memory exhausted despide big SWAP?

Tags: pi-3, memory, gcc, swap-space

I want to build [Iroha hyperledger](https://github.com/hyperledger/iroha) on Raspberry Pi 3. So I've downloaded code and all dependencies and compiler gcc-8.2 (downloaded precompiled from [here](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/12/07/raspberry-pi-raspbian-compiling-gcc/)), then configured without tests:

```
cmake -DTESTING=OFF -LA ../
```

but when I run **make**: it is stopping on file: **iroha/irohad/main/impl/on_demand_ordering_init.cpp**. I read in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819934/compiling-phalcon-virtual-memory-exhausted-cannot-allocate-memory) about creating swap file, so I've even created swap partition 30G and the problem still happen. By the way I've noticed in htop, that compilation does not use more than 1G RAM + 600M swap memory but it shows "*virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory*". I've also tried to do like described in [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20141202015428/http://hostingfu.com/article/compiling-with-gcc-on-low-memory-vps) to add extra flags to g++:

```
--param ggc-min-expand=0 --param ggc-min-heapsize=8192
```

I've also tried to increade vm.max_map_count value as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414228/problem-with-gcc-allocated-memory-on-vps):

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262140 # default was 65535
```

I've also tried to compile the file by hand, thanks to adding a flag to make the compiling command was visible:

```
make VERBOSE=1

cd /home/pi/Desktop/iroha/zbudowane/irohad/main && /usr/bin/c++ --param ggc-min-expand=0 --param ggc-min-heapsize=8192  -DBOOST_NO_RTTI -I/home/pi/Desktop/iroha/irohad -I/home/pi/Desktop/iroha/libs -I/home/pi/Desktop/iroha/shared_model -I/home/pi/Desktop/iroha/zbudowane/schema -isystem /usr/local/include -isystem /usr/include/soci -isystem /usr/include/postgresql  -std=c++14 -fdiagnostics-color=always -g -O0 -fPIC   -o CMakeFiles/application.dir/impl/on_demand_ordering_init.o -c /home/pi/Desktop/iroha/irohad/main/impl/on_demand_ordering_init.cpp
```

but the problem is still occuring. The bad thing is that it is last file to fully compile entire project:D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some hack to compile the file, but it is not sure that this won't make any troubles in future.
I've run gcc's preprocessor on the file (**-E** flag) in Raspberry:

```
/usr/bin/c++ -E -DBOOST_NO_RTTI -I/home/pi/Desktop/iroha/irohad -I/home/pi/Desktop/iroha/libs -I/home/pi/Desktop/iroha/shared_model -I/home/pi/Desktop/iroha/zbudowane/schema -isystem /usr/local/include -isystem /usr/include/soci -isystem /usr/include/postgresql -std=c++14 -Wall -fdiagnostics-color=always -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-deprecated-declarations -O0 -fPIC -o CMakeFiles/application.dir/impl/on_demand_ordering_init_prep.o -c /home/pi/Desktop/iroha/irohad/main/impl/on_demand_ordering_init.cpp
```

then I got 6M file, which I've compiled on my PC with command:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-8 -std=c++14 -fdiagnostics-color=always -g -O0 -fPIC -o CMakeFiles/application.dir/impl/on_demand_ordering_init.o -c CMakeFiles/application.dir/impl/on_demand_ordering_init_prep.cpp
```

then I've copied the file to raspberry and compilation of entire project succeed. It also looks that Iroha server is working, but I'm not sure if it is going to crash or not.

Comment: It seems that cross compiling for ARM is more common than self hosted. ARM boards don't have the same level of processing speed and it seems people don't want to wait as long as it would take to build on ARM. Because of that self hosted compiling doesn't seem to be as robust as cross compiling.

Comment: This command worked for me


arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -std=c++14 -fdiagnostics-color=always -g -O0 -fPIC -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -mtls-dialect=gnu -o ./on_demand_ordering_init.o -c ./on_demand_ordering_init_prep.cpp


I was getting VFP compatibility issue, have to set that explicitly while building

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: @Ingo: done, but my answer is rather hack than solution of problem